# Fast image RGB to BGR conversion

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, simd, simd-library

I need to perform conversion of images from BGR to RGB image format and also backward conversion. I found [Simd Library](http://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) which contains function [SimdBgrToRgb](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__bgr__conversion.html#ga0ec8d4dc18f9cdbdaf2e300a101e8a40) which performs fast conversion from BGR to RGB.
But I didn't find any function for backward (RGB to BGR) conversion.

Maight any to know any C/C++ library which allows to perform this conversion?

Comment: The same function goes backwards as well. It swaps B and R, the opposite of a swap is that same swap

Comment: Isn't the conversion symmetric?

Comment: The documentation you linked even says "also it performs backward conversion".

Comment: So I can use the same (SimdBgrToRgb) function?

Comment: @William Unless the meaning of English words have changed dramatically recently, yes. (Note that the documentation for the result parameter is obviously wrong, though.)

Comment: Equally, you could potentially use the somewhat more mainstream OpenCV library which has SIMD-optimised `cvtColor(image,COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 24bpp images, it's the same shuffle: reverse 3-byte chunks.  For 16bpp 5:6:5 image formats, it's again the same shuffle with symmetry around the middle field.

**Use any of the existing BGR to RGB functions you found.**